# AS3 for transfering pauseposition of MC1 to MC2

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, position, adobe, playback

Hi I'm quite a new on flash and need some code. I have 3 MCs say `MC1`, `MC2` and `MC3`. I will have 3 dedicated buttons that will pause the music of one MC and transfer the frame position to another MC and start playing. so say for example if `MC2` is playing and I press the `MC3` button I would like it to take the pause position of `MC2` (not `MC1`) and continue playing from that frame on `MC3` as well as switching the visuals from `MC2` to `MC3`. it's a Multilingual app and all 3 MC's have the same frame length. in other words I would like to switch between languages. 
Thanks in advance, any help would be great.

EDIT: up till now I have

```
mtlyrvult.stop();
itlyrvult.stop();

engvult.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMC1); 

function playMC1(e:MouseEvent):void {
    itlyrvult.stop();
    enlyrvult.gotoAndPlay(itlyrvult.currentFrame);
    itlyrvult.gotoAndStop(1);  //frame one is empty
    engvult.mouseEnabled = false;
    itvult.mouseEnabled = true;
}

itvult.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMC2); 

function playMC2(e:MouseEvent):void {
    enlyrvult.stop();
    itlyrvult.gotoAndPlay(enlyrvult.currentFrame);
    enlyrvult.gotoAndStop(1);    //frame one is empty
    itvult.mouseEnabled = false;
    engvult.mouseEnabled = true;
}
```

This switches from one language to another. Now my client gave me another language. `mtlyrvult`. And I don't know how AS3 will recognise which mc is playing to take the the pauseposition/currentframe from it.

Comment: Can you post some code lines, that will help to understand what you're trying to do ?

Comment: What do you mean by "as well as switching the visuals from `MC2` to `MC3`." ?

Comment: meant to say that whichever mc is being paused needs to 'disappear' to make room for the new MC. that is dealt with the gotoAndStop(1). First frame of the MC is empty.

Comment: I think I got it.  See my answer. Tell me if anything's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stick to your code (no class, method, members, addChild, ...). I didn't try the final draft with Flash or SDK.

I assume that you have:

- 3 [MovieClip](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) objects : `enlyrvult`, `itlyrvult`, `mtlyrvult`;
- 3 [InteractiveObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html) (SimpleButton, MovieClip, ...) objects : `engvult`, `itvult`, `mtvult`;
- and that `enlyrvult` is playing when we begin here (if not: `enlyrvult.play();` or `enlyrvult.stop();`).

---

```
itlyrvult.stop();  // or itlyrvult.gotoAndStop(1); 
mtlyrvult.stop();  // or mtlyrvult.gotoAndStop(1);

engvult.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMC1); 
itvult.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMC2); 
mtvult.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMC3); 

// play enlyrvult
function playMC1(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // stop them
    itlyrvult.stop();
    mtlyrvult.stop();

    // play me
    enlyrvult.gotoAndPlay(mtlyrvult.currentFrame);

    // hide them
    itlyrvult.gotoAndStop(1);    //frame one is empty
    mtlyrvult.gotoAndStop(1);    //frame one is empty

    // My trigger is out, theirs are fine
    engvult.mouseEnabled = false;
    itvult.mouseEnabled = true;
    mtvult.mouseEnabled = true;
}

// play itlyrvult
function playMC2(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // stop them
    enlyrvult.stop();
    mtlyrvult.stop();

    // play me
    itlyrvult.gotoAndPlay(enlyrvult.currentFrame);

    // hide them
    enlyrvult.gotoAndStop(1);    //frame one is empty
    mtlyrvult.gotoAndStop(1);    //frame one is empty

    // My trigger is out, theirs are fine
    itvult.mouseEnabled = false;
    engvult.mouseEnabled = true;
    mtvult.mouseEnabled = true;
} 

// play mtlyrvult
function playMC3(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // stop them
    enlyrvult.stop();
    itlyrvult.stop();

    // play me
    mtlyrvult.gotoAndPlay(itlyrvult.currentFrame);

    // hide them
    enlyrvult.gotoAndStop(1);    //frame one is empty
    itlyrvult.gotoAndStop(1);    //frame one is empty

    // My trigger is out, theirs are fine
    mtvult.mouseEnabled = false;
    engvult.mouseEnabled = true;
    itvult.mouseEnabled = true;
}
```

OR, for as much (300?) as you want...

```
// add to your import:
import flash.utils.Dictionary;

// in your const/var section
const STARTING_FRAME:int = 1;
var dict = new Dictionary();  // mapping and memory
var currentTrack:MovieClip;   // we will know who's last

initAll();
playTrack(enlyrvult, STARTING_FRAME, engvult);

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var playheadFrame:int = currentTrack.currentFrame;                      // we remember position
    var trigger:InteractiveObject = (e.currentTarget as InteractiveObject); // who shot me ?
    var nextTrack:MovieClip = (dict[trigger] as MovieClip);                 // who's next ?

    resetAll();  // and again.. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus)
    playTrack(nextTrack, playheadFrame, trigger);
}

function playTrack(mc:MovieClip, fram:int, iObj:InteractiveObject):void {
    currentTrack = mc;
    currentTrack.gotoAndPlay(fram);
    iObj.mouseEnabled = false;
}

function resetAll():void {
   for (var key:InteractiveObject in dict) { key.mouseEnabled = true; }
   for each (var value:MovieClip in dict) { value.gotoAndStop(1); } // diff-> each
} 

function initAll():void {
   dict[engvult] = enlyrvult;
   dict[itvult] = itlyrvult;
   dict[mtvult] = mtlyrvult;
   //dict[avult] = alyrvult; //<- new one like this: dict[trigger]=lyrMC; add as much as you can!

   for (var key:InteractiveObject in dict) {
       key.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
   }

   resetAll();
}
```